# Taking String from a file, and then placing each number into a 2D Array. (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, 2d

I'm having quite a lot of issues when it comes to parsing through a stringBuffer into a 2D Array.

This is what I am trying to achieve....

This is an example of one of my files.

```
 123456789
 123456789
 123456789
 123456789
 123456789
 123456789
 123456789
 123456789
 123456789
```

and if I was just to manually write it into Java I would get...

```
int[][] board = {
   {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
   {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
   {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
   {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
   {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
   {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
   {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
   {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},
   {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},       
};
```

But I'm trying to create a method which does it for us, seeing as I'm loading in many different files.

This is my code.

```
        int[][] board = new int[9][9];

        File file = new File ("keiron.sud");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String newline;
        while ((newline = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(newline);
            stringBuffer.append("\n");
        }
        fileReader.close();
        String data =  stringBuffer.toString();
        int counting = data.length();
        int counter = 0;

        int i,j;

        for(i = 0; i<9; i++) {
            for (j =0; j < 9; j++) {
                int numbers = data.charAt(counter);
                counter++;

            board[i][j] = numbers;

            }
        }
        Print(board);
```

And this is the output I'm getting

```
49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 
10 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 
57 10 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 
56 57 10 49 50 51 52 53 54 
55 56 57 10 49 50 51 52 53 
54 55 56 57 10 49 50 51 52 
53 54 55 56 57 10 49 50 51 
52 53 54 55 56 57 10 49 50 
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 10 49
```

Which really doesn't make sense!

I'm fairly new to Java, so please can you explain things like you would to a 5 year old!

Thank you,

CodeMonkey

Comment: Don't add that to your question. Post it as a comment to my answer and I would help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing this

```
int numbers = data.charAt(counter); // char to int
```

you're getting the [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/) of the numbers.

On the LHS you've an `int` and on the RHS you've a method `charAt()` which returns a `char`. Therefore, the ASCII value of the char on the RHS is being assigned to the `int` on the LHS.

To get the actual numeric value, use this

```
int numbers = Character.getNumericValue(data.charAt(counter)); // fetches the numeric value
```

You'll get a `-1` in between, because you're adding a `\n` manually within your string. Remove that and it won't show that `-1`.

```
// stringBuffer.append("\n"); // This is unnecessary. Comment it out.
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `int numbers = data.charAt(counter);` to `int numbers = data.charAt(j)-'0';`

and consider remove the space in data

```
 String data =  stringBuffer.toString().trim();
 data = data.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Comment: Ideally I would like to have it so it changes " " into a 0.